# GWT FlexTable scroll to a specific row

Tags: css, gwt, scroll, flextable

Is there any way we can scroll flextable to a specific selected row?

What I am trying to achieve is that I have two panes, `LeftView` and `RightView`. Based on selecting an item on the `RightView` `FlexTable` should scroll to that selected item in the `LeftView`.

Comment: I have not worked with a `FlexTable` yet, but it looks like you have to add a `TableListener` to the `FlexTable` of the `RightView` and select the appropriate cell in the `FlexTable of the `LeftView`. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your FlexTable is inside of a ScrollPanel.

And each cell of the FlexTable has some other widget.

So what you need is to use

ScrollPanel [void ensureVisible(UIObject item)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html#ensureVisible%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.UIObject%29)